# Function after finishing two other functions. Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have these two functions in my Angular 5 controller.

I need that when both have finished without error, to do another function, but only when they have finished and they are without error the two.

Can someone help me to merge them?

**CONTROLLER**

```
empleadosAltas() {
    this.empleadoService.empleadosAltas({
        anno: this.annoFilter
    }).subscribe(
        (result) => {
            //result
        }
        (error) => {
           //error
        });


empleadosBajas() {
    this.empleadoService.empleadosBajas({
        anno: this.annoFilter
    }).subscribe(
        (result) => {
            //result
        }
        (error) => {
           //error
        });
```

**SERVICES**

```
empleadosAltas(req?: any): Observable<Map<number, Array<Empleado>>> {
    const options = createRequestOption(req);
    options.params.set('anno', req.anno);
    return this.http.get(this.resourceUrl + '/altas-empleado', options).map((res: Response) => {
        return res.json();
    });
}

empleadosBajas(req?: any): Observable<Map<number, Array<Empleado>>> {
    const options = createRequestOption(req);
    options.params.set('anno', req.anno);
    return this.http.get(this.resourceUrl + '/altas-empleado', options).map((res: Response) => {
        return res.json();
    });
}
```

Comment: you can use `forkJoin` to combine the observables.

Comment: like this `Observable.forkJoin(first,second).subscribe((res:Array) =>  console.log(res) );`

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` operator (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html)

```
zip(
    this.empleadoService.empleadosAltas({
        anno: this.annoFilter
    }),
    this.empleadoService.empleadosBajas({
        anno: this.annoFilter
    })
)
.pipe(
    take(1),
)
.subscribe([atlas, bajas] => {
    // your code here
});
```

Zip waits for both observables to emit values. `pipe` with `take(1)` makes sure that it works only for the first emission so you don't have to unsubscribe.

EDIT:
After seeing the comments to your qustion I agree that forkJoin is a better solution.

Comment: forJoin executes in parallel and subscriber won't receive any values until both observables have completed.

Answer (score 0):

Use Promise to handle rejection. combineFunction() { let array = []; array.push( new Promise(resolve, reject) => { this.empleadoService.empleadosAltas({ anno: this.annoFilter }).then(res=>{ resolve(res) }).catch(err=>{ reject(err) }) })) array.push( new Promise(resolve, reject) => { this.empleadosBajas.empleadosAltas({ anno: this.annoFilter }).then(res=>{ resolve(res) }).catch(err=>{ reject(err) }) })) return Promise.all(array); }